# Hovering images main menu

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is when I hover title and as you can see there is little white arrow, but when I go  over the subtitle that image disappears.

[image]

```
#menu {
    float: left;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#menu .menu_layer {
    float: left;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100%;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-top: #D8D6D2 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #F5F3F0 1px solid;
    background: #ffffff;
    z-index: 99;
}
#menu .menu_list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#menu .menu_list .egNav_menu_box {
    width: 940px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egMenuLevel_0 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egMenuLevel_0 a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 48px;
    font-family: "open_sanslight";
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666666;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egMenuLevel_0:first-child a {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egMenuLevel_0 a:hover {
    color: #4E2581;
    background: url("/resources/images/bg_menu_hover2.png") no-repeat center bottom;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egSelected.egMenuLevel_0 a {
    color: #4E2582;
    background: url("/resources/images/bg_menu_hover.png") no-repeat center bottom;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egSelected.egMenuLevel_0 .egMenuLevel_1 a {
    color: #666666;
    background-image: none;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egSelected.egMenuLevel_0 .egMenuLevel_1 a:hover {
    color: #4E2581;
}
#menu .egNav_menu_box .egMenuLevel_0 a.sub_menu_link:hover {
    color: #4E2581;
}
```

Comment: 1. What are you trying to achieve/what is the question? 2. Please post some html or make a fiddle

Comment: Could you format the code and the question in a clearer way pls?

Comment: please post your HTML markup

Comment: I guess you want to keep the arrow even when you rollover the subtitle right?

Comment: Then the arrow should be in the submenu, absolutely positioned or with negative top margin.

Comment: There is no html,  there is XML file for rendering.
@Alex Garulli  yes.

Can i do it with javascript ?

Comment: u don't need JS to do that. It s CSS ..answer above ..arrow should be in the submenu, absolutely positioned or with negative top margin ..did u try that?

Comment: somehow i made it with JS :), Thanks people oon your time